# How to simulate a server reboot task for Unit Testing - Java?

Tags: java, testng

I need to unit test a 'wait for reboot' action written in my code. The code waits upto a specified timeout value given by the user for the server to restart and come up. When the timeout value is elapsed, it will throw a Timed out exception.

To test that, I need to simulate the behaviour of a server reboot. Is that really possible??

Note: I am using TestNG framework for my unit testing.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail? Presumably your code is running as a client. How does it detect that the server has rebooted?

Comment: It can be done, but it depends on the abstractions that you have in place.  Can you post a small snippet that shows where you are?

Answer (score 0):

Well, In a simple manner, listen to different port OR different URL. It simulates server is down.

You can wait for some time in thread and change back URL to correct to simulate server UP!